# Is it safe to use get_or_create_indexed_node() to guarantee property uniqueness in neo4j? Use as a foreign key

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm using python+py2neo with neo4j  I am assigning my SQL db's auto-assigned record ID as a foreign key in my neo4j database.

I'm using get_or_create_indexed_node() to create a new node with a unique id if a node with this ID does not already exist in the neo database.

```
neo4jdb.get_or_create_indexed_node(index='Company', key='cid', value=self.id, properties={'cid' : self.id})
```

...using py2neo's wrapping of the neo REST interface.  Is this safe?  I think a couple times it may still have duplicated, creating new nodes with the same ID.  Is there a better way to do this, ensuring uniqueness of an id foreign key across nodes of the same index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be perfectly safe as the method is a simple wrapper around the API call; it does not carry out any of the uniqueness management on the client side. Are you able to show some code which produces these duplicates?

Cheers, Nige

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate it since, which is weird.  So I'll assume it's fine.  Thanks for making an excellently useful library, Nigel!